# "Opportunity of purchasing" vs "Opportunity to purchase"

Tags: grammar, verbs

I am translating a phrase from Spanish and I would appreciate the input from a native English speaker:

I translated a phrase as "to give the opportunity of purchasing", but I am in doubt whether it would be more appropriate "to give the opportunity to purchase". Which one is the correct phrase?

Comment: I don't think it's off topic, since you're not just asking "translate this for me" but rather "I translated it like this, is it correct or wrong?"

Comment: @Alenanno I thought so, but since this is my first question in English.SE I'm not so sure about the rules here. Thus, I rather make sure :)

Comment: Good good :) from my experience here, I could see not all do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical.

**"opportunity to do something"**
will put more emphasis on **"opportunity"** while **"opportunity of doing something"** will relatively put more on **"doing something"**, I mean in written English.

Answer (score 2):

The second one feels much more natural to me.  I'm not sure that there's anything wrong with the first one though.

Answer (score 2):

The more normal English expression would be

**chance to buy** (general-purpose, conversation)

or possibly, dependent on context

**offer for sale** (adverts) or **option to purchase** (legal small print)

There's nothing wrong with *opportunity* or *purchase*, but they are a bit 'wordy'

Comment: It *is* a wordy original, and I am trying to keep the style as close as possible. I'll keep your options for my every day language, though :)

Comment: @Aleadam: not sure we both mean the same thing by 'wordy' then. In the UK, for example, if a new company is floated on the Stock Exchange, the publicised application details (which are definitely not 'everyday' language) are normally entitled **Offer to Purchase**. Here's an example template, so you can see it's not 'informal' at all  http://www.jurifax.com/extracts/1810Econ.pdf

Comment: ...and it's partly a matter of style whether you offer **for sale**, or **to purchase**. But the former is more common for 'tangibles' (property, etc.), the latter for things like equities.

Comment: I meant 'wordy' as a text full of long words and convoluted. In my every day language I would use 'chance to buy' instead. If I could rewrite the original, it would be 2 pages long, instead of 7 :P Regarding 'sale' or 'purchase', I believe the emphasis here is in the buyer, rather than the seller, so I prefer 'purchase'. It's about one of the big car companies making the policies for employees car pricing. The phrase is about the employee's right to buy a discounted car, not about the right of the company to sell it.

Comment: @Aleadam: oic. I think the normal English wording in that context is **Option to purchase**. That's what you usually get in the small print when dealerships sell/lease a new car for, say, 3 years at a fixed monthly price. At the end of the agreement period, you either just return the vehicle, or buy it for a fixed price which was defined in the original agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, depending on the context of the sentence, the phrase "give a purchasing opportunity" may be more idiomatic.

Comment: I like it, thanks! (unfortunately I already sent that translation)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/opportunity_1), both your phrases are right:

> - **opportunity (to do something)** *You'll have the opportunity to ask any questions at the end.*
> - *This is the perfect opportunity to make a new start.*
> - **opportunity (for something/for doing something)** *There was no opportunity for further discussion.*
> - *There’ll be plenty of opportunity for relaxing once the work is done.*
> - **opportunity (of doing something)** *At least give him the opportunity of explaining what happened.*

So, looking at your examples:

- **opportunity (to do something)** *to give the opportunity to purchase*
- **opportunity (of doing something)** *to give the opportunity of purchasing*

It would also be right:

- **opportunity (for something/for doing something)** *to give the opportunity **for purchasing*